# Calculating Irrationals raised to some Power modulo 1000000007

Tags: modular-arithmetic, fibonacci-numbers

Lets define a function F as
$F(n) = 1+(\frac{1+{\sqrt 5}}{2})^n$
As per wolfram site, [${\sqrt 5}\%99991=10104$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=powermod%5B5,+1%2F2,+99991%5D)
As per wolfram site, [${\sqrt 5}\%1000000007=no\_solution$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=powermod%5B5,+1%2F2,+1000000007%5D)
I need to **find the value of** $F(n)\%MOD $, where $MOD = 1000000007$ for very large $n<10^9$. Unfortunately ${\sqrt 5}\%MOD$ doesn't has an integer solution for $MOD = 1e9+7$. How shall I proceed?

Comment: I suspect there is some recurrence relation involved behind how $F(n)$ is defined. If so can you provide the recurrence here? (I smell Fibonacci - ish)

Comment: That modulo looks like Project Euler

Comment: Try adding $\left(\frac{1-\sqrt5}{2}\right)^n$ (which becomes very small as $n$ increases) and expand with the binomial theorem. If that is what you're after.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is related to an active competition:  https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to compute Fibonacci numbers using a variant of Binet's formula (though you're forgetting to divide by $\sqrt5$ if that's your plan).

Unfortunately your approach to finding the remainder of the Fibonacci number doesn't really work here. I think you're trying to do modular reduction during the computation, applying the rule
$$ ab \bmod n = (a \bmod n)(b \bmod n) \bmod n$$
to push the modulo operations inwards in the computation.

Unfortunately the above rule only works when $a$ and $b$ are *integers*, and Binet's formula requires a power of a *non-integer*, so doing the entire computation modularly from the beginning is a non-starter.

---

A better way to compute modular Fibonacci numbers is the matrix equation
$$ \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}^n = 
\begin{pmatrix}F_{n+1} & F_n \\ F_n & F_{n-1} \end{pmatrix} $$
Because the matrices here always have *integer* entries you *can* do this computation modulo 1000000007 at each step. Combined with exponentiation by squaring this will allow you to compute modular Fibonacci numbers at feasible cost.

---

(Actually, the full Binet formula
$$ F_n = \frac{\bigl(\frac{1+\sqrt5}2\bigr)^n-\bigl(\frac{1-\sqrt5}2\bigr)^n}{\sqrt5} $$
*will* work in any field where the characteristic polynomial of $({}^1_1\,{}^1_0)$ splits -- that is, in any field of characteristic $\ne 2$ where $5$ has a square root -- but in general the right-hand power can't be replaced by a final round-to-integer step like it can in $\mathbb R$. So in principle you *can* use Binet's formula by doing your calculation in $\mathbb F_{1000000007^2}\cong\mathbb Z_{1000000007}[\sqrt 5]$ -- but it's not clear to me that this is more efficient than the matrix calculation above).

Comment: I need to separate my fibonacci number into $a(b^n - c^n)$. I know about the matrix exponentiation, but that is not what I really need.

Comment: @maverick: $a=F_n$, $b=1$, $c=0$?

Comment: I could not get your last paragraph about how I can use Binet's formula. In this case, I am dealing with irrationals, and ${\sqrt 5}\%MOD$ doesn't has integer solutions for $MOD = 1e9+7.$ So how can I proceed in this? Also it would be helpful if you could explain what does ${\mathbb{Z}}$ means. I couldn't get that part.

Comment: @maverick: Work with numbers of the form $p+q\alpha$, where $p$ and $q$ are integers modulo $10^9+7$ and $\alpha$ is a formal unknown whose behavior is defined by $\alpha^2=5$.

Comment: @maverick: $\mathbb Z$ is standard notation for the set of integers: $\mathbb Z=\{\ldots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots\}$. $\mathbb Z_k$ is the integers modulo $k$.

Comment: $a = {\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}}$, b and c are roots of $x^2-x-1=0$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37851/discussion-between-maverick-and-henning-makholm).

Comment: This problem is part of an ongoing competition:  https://www.codechef.com/APRIL16/problems/FIBQ

Comment: @lulu: Good catch. Fortunately the question was deep enough into "XY problem" territory that this answer doesn't really address the interesting parts of the challenge.